# more then one form element can be present in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, forms

hi all i want to know is it possible that in one aspx page there will be more then one form
element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible

check this : [Multiple form-based programming in ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avi_sanjay/MultiForms.htm06042006062957AM/MultiForms.htm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Form-based Programming in ASP.NET - Multiple form tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx#S4)